# TestNG Selenium WebElement cannot find

Tags: java, selenium, testng-dataprovider

Below is my code running script through TestNG. It fails to find the web element username and the error I get (screenshot attached). Please advise.

[image]
@Test

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
String baseURL = "http://mapp.com";
Driver.get(baseURL);
String UserName = "*****";
String Password = "*****";
WebElement username = Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#Login"));
```

Comment: Are you able to find the element in DevTools? Is the css selector correct?

Comment: There is no login present on http://mapp.com

Comment: It works with JAVA compiler. it fails when i remove JAVA and run with TestNG

Comment: Are you sure you are executing your login operation on http://mapp.com?

Comment: No, it was a fake URL.. My URL is different!! But definitely CSS selector is correct.. My question is why it fails when runs with Test NG

Comment: This time I'm getting this error!!  FAILED:                                                        main
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Test.MockTestNG.main(MockTestNG.java:33)

Comment: @Rocky Which line is line 33?

Comment: I wasted my time with the "fake url" too.  Can you at least post a snippet of the HTML please?